# Generate List of Installed Packages with TeX Live

Tags: texlive, tlmgr

I've been trying to generate a list of all packages that can be accessed using the `\usepackage` command in LaTeX & others (so it can be autocompleted by my text editor). Specifically, I've been using the command `tlmgr list --only-installed` and parsing the output. However, I've noticed that several (key) packages are missing from the output. For example, `tikz`, `graphicx`, `lmodern` and some others are not present.

At first, I used the answer [given here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341789/tlmgr-packages-not-present-in-repository/341813#341813) to manually add the missing packages to the list. However, I noticed that `tikz` was also missing from the output. Now I have no idea which packages may be omitted, even though they are installed. To make things worse, it seems there are several "packages" that are not actually meant to be used as packages. David Carlisle's answer to the linked question explains that `tlmgr` treats packages differently to LaTeX, which only makes things harder.

Is there a `tlmgr` terminal command that will print a list of all packages that can be `\usepackage`'d in a `.tex` file (`pdftex`, `luatex`, `xetex`, etc. differences are not important)?

If not, is there any way at all to do this? The goal is to make it cross platform too, so a solution should be adaptable to Linux, macOS, and Windows. I have not tried MikTeX yet, but it needs to work with a standard TeX Live installation.

Finally, short of that solution, is there an *exhaustive* list of packages that are omitted?

Comment: You could search all folders known to TeX for *.sty files and sort this list.

Comment: Do you get an error from `tlmgr list --only-installed`? I do.

Comment: @cfr No, no error. I think I set permissions up leniently when I installed, so that could be it.

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: No, macOS. But it works on Windows too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bash
tlmgr search --file '.*\.sty'
```

Note that this will find files installed with `tlmgr`. I assume, from your question, that it is these you are interested in. Obviously, other `.sty` files may be available locally, in addition to those installed with `tlmgr`, but, equally obviously, `tlmgr` knows nothing about those.

Comment: This still doesn't find the missing packages. The biggest problem with the `tlmgr` search was that I didn't know which were missing. I've resorted to recursively searching `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex` (I'll add local package support a different way), but it would be nice if the output came with a small summary of the package's purpose, like the `tlmgr list --only-installed` does.

Comment: @BenjaminGray What does it not find? You wanted to find everything you can use `\usepackage{}` with i.e. `.sty` files. Which `.sty` file installed by TL does it not find?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see them as part of a file path. They are there.

Comment: @BenjaminGray I ran a comparison with `find`. The command I gave finds everything `find` finds. In addition, it finds some other files which I guess it classifies as of type `.sty`, even though they do not have this extension. (It seems to find anything with a `.sty` in it, even if it is not the extension.)

Comment: Also, your question didn't say anything about a 'small summary of the package's purpose'. It doesn't really make sense to ask for that for each `.sty` file, because some of them have no stand-alone purpose. For example, a package in the install-sense may contain several `.sty` files (if any). I start to think this is an XY problem. I guess I'm no longer clear what you're trying to do at all.

Comment: ignore the part about the summary. It was not important. FYI, I did say at the start that it was for an autocomplete service, so the summary would have been used as a short description. But it was always the valid packages I wanted / cared about.

Comment: @BenjaminGray My autocomplete doesn't give me a summary (thank goodness).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71700/discussion-between-benjamin-gray-and-cfr).